# Deleted .bashrc line, how to set path to ROS?

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted the last line in the .bashrc file in my newly installed cturtle ROS under Ubuntu 10.10. Now no ROS commands will work as it cannot find the ROS path.
I have found 'setup.bash' in the \opt\ros\cturtle path and presume this will update the .bashrc ?
As a newcomer to Linux, how do I run 'setup.bash' or, what line must be in .bashrc ?
Sorry for doing such a dumb move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9501/deleted-.bashrc-line,-how-to-set-path-to-ros?/) by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to get the ROS commands back, you simply have to run:

```
source /opt/ros/<DISTRO>/setup.bash
```

You can also add this command to the bottom of your .bashrc file.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2011-03-26**:
gedit works a treat, so much easier, I'll use that for now.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-21**:
VIM is a hard place to start if you are just getting started with Linux.  Check out vimtutor if you are serious about VIM.  Also, feel free to use nano or gedit while you are getting familiar with the command line.

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2011-03-21**:
THANK YOU! Works perfectly. Will try to learn how to use vi properly before editing .bashrc again!